# Matched leaf route at location "/" does not have an element react-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

My app.js component code  is given below
I am using the render syntax for components with props in 
I have checked the syntax for calling component with props using render method, it is exactly the same
plus i am following a video tutorial he is also using the same syntax
what am i missing?
what went wrong?

```
import React,{useState,useEffect} from 'react';
import { v4 as uuid } from 'uuid';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import  './App.css';
import Header from "./Header";
import AddContact from "./AddContact";
import ContactList from "./ContactList";

function App() {
  const LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY ="contacts";
  const [contacts, setContacts]=useState([]);
  const addContactHandler = (contact)=>{
    console.log(contact);
    setContacts([...contacts,{id: uuid(), ...contact}]);
  };

  const removeContactHandler =(id)=>{
    const newContactList = contacts.filter((contact)=>{
      return contact.id !== id;
    });

    setContacts(newContactList);
  };

  useEffect(()=>{

    const retriveContacts = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY));
    if (retriveContacts)  setContacts(retriveContacts);
  },[]);
  useEffect(()=>{
    localStorage.setItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(contacts));
  },[contacts]);
  return (
    <div className='ui container'>
      <Router>
        <Header/>
        <Routes>
        
          <Route path="/" render={(props)=> (<ContactList {...props} contacts={contacts} getContactId = {removeContactHandler}/>) } />
          <Route path="/add" render={(props)=>(<AddContact {...props} addContactHandler={addContactHandler}/>)} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
      
      
      
      {/*<AddContact addContactHandler={addContactHandler}/>
      <ContactList contacts={contacts} getContactId = {removeContactHandler}/> */}
    </div>
    
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: You can check this out https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-leftpad-70d1z9?file=/src/App.js

Comment: What version of react router dom are you using?

Comment: I am using version 6

Comment: @AmanSadhwani  this is an example of simple routing. the issue i am facing is i am using props in the component as well.

Comment: You are following an outdated tutorial that is using `react-router-dom@5`. The APIs and syntax changed significantly from v5 to v6. In v6 the `Route` component renders its content on the `element` prop as a `ReactNode`. There are no longer any route props, the components instead use React hooks to access what they need from RRD.

Comment: @DrewReese can you refer me to V6 tutorial for this issue ?

Comment: @DrewReese i followed the same syntax for V5 now, error is removed. But my components are stillnot showing properly  o```bject { history: {…}, location: {…}, match: {…}, staticContext: undefined, contacts: [], getContactId: removeContactHandler(id)``` but inspect is showing this right now

Comment: See the [Upgrading from v5](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5) guide for all the breaking changes from `react-router` v5 to v6. Sorry, I don't quite follow your second comment.